# Run-time component package requires itself further to a refactoring

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, package, delphi-xe2

I have a set of components in split runtime/designtime packages for Delphi XE2. I've had these for a long time and have had no problems like what I'm having now. I added a new basic control called `TJDWebcam`. All was fine until I decided to change the type name to `TJDWebcamView`. I did a find/replace in the main source unit where I have this class, and made some other changes, also in the design-time package's registration unit.

The problem is that now when I build the run-time package, I get a message saying that it requires its self (It requires a package `JDComponents` which is exactly the same package). I've uninstalled the package, and tried to re-build, but same error.

Here's the specific message I'm getting...

```
Add JDComponents.
JDComponents contains implicit unit(s) uPickFolder, JDCommon, 
JD.VSample, JD.VFrames, NativeJpg.
```

...and every unit in the package which are OK to be there. The problem didn't start until I changed this control's type name and went to re-compile.

Now if I ignore that message and hit 'Cancel' everything seems to install fine, despite the warning that it "might cause errors".

For what reasons might it be doing this? And how to go about fixing it? I'd hate to have to post my entire component library to be debugged.

PS - My library makes use of the delphi version suffix (160 for XE2) and my own version suffix (2), so the package names actually read `JDComponents.160.bpl.2` and `DCLJDComponents.160.bpl.2`.

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it installed, please see my answer below.

Comment: You can give the solution as an answer and accept it. That is the appropriate way here at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing these following steps, I managed to get it re-built successfully:

- Uninstalled the package
- Deleted all DCU's, package, and anything compiled
- Restarted the PC
- Re-build everything

So the source of the problem is still unknown, but most likely somewhere in a compiled file (DCU or the package), it was still referring to this old type name from before it got changed. When the compiler came across this, it got confused and told me I had to include this other package, which is actually the same package.